# How can I align both boxes, one in top of the other having same size

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am trying to align both of the boxes shown in the code below, using bootstrap flex and grid classes, but somehow both of them have different width.

I tried setting the width of both to width=200px; to see what happened, and flex items lose position.

```
<!-- total income -->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="budget__income d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
                        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center col-xs-1">
                            <div class="budget__income--text py-3">
                                <strong>Ingresos</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="budget__income--value py-3">
                                + 4,300 </div>
                            <div class="buget__income--percentage py-3 pl-2 align-self-center ">
                                34%
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- total expense -->
                    <div class="budget__expense d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center col-xs-1">
                            <div class="budget__expense--text py-3">
                                <strong>Gastos</strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="budget__expense--value py-3">
                                + 4,300 </div>
                            <div class="buget__expense--percentage py-3 pl-2 align-self-center ">
                                22%
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I expect to have both of the specified boxes aligned horizontally, and both having the same width.

Thank you so much,

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

try with table, table-row and table-cell display. Like:

```
<div style="display: table">
  <div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      content1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-row">
    <div style="display: table-cell">
      content2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```